# Array.splice replaces multiple values (though set to replace only one)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In order to learn coding I set about making my own small idle-clicker-RPG in Javascript and HTML. Now my Inventory-management-codes are giving me quite the headache, as it doesnt remove and add items 1:1 but rather duplicates them (see later). But I'm at a loss to why. It appears only to happen, when the items share the same 'type' (see code)

I've trimmed the code down in order to figure out where. Made variables to let, changed order and timing (added settimeout), cut up the 'splice' function and used separate for deleting and adding.

### HTML

---

```
<td><p><div id="Pos1" onclick="equip(Inventory[0], 0)"></div></td>
etc....
```

### JavaScript

---

```
var Stick = {
    Type : "MainHand",
};

var Knife = {
    Type : "MainHand",
};

var Inventory = [];

var Equipped = {
    MainHand : {Name : ""},
};

function equip(item, position){
    let LItem = item;
    let LPosition = position;
    let EQItem = Equipped[LItem.Type]
    if (EQItem.Name !== "") {
    Inventory.splice(LPosition, 1, EQItem);
    Object.assign(EQItem, LItem);
    } else {
    Object.assign(EQItem, LItem);
    Inventory.splice(LPosition, 1);
    };
};
```

I want the function 'equip' to do the following when an item is presset in inventory through html:

1. check that an item isn't already equipped at that spot

1.1 remove selected item from inventory

1.2 add currently equipped item to inventory

1.3 equip selected item

> 2. if nothing is equipped (2. through 2.2 works as intended)
>
> 2.1 remove selected item from inventory
>
> 2.2 equip selected item

What happens at 1.1-1.3 is that (I'm not sure about the order) the selected item is equipped, but then the unequipped item (that seems to get added to the inventory) and the rest of the items of same type a randomly changed to the selected item. This doesn't happen to all items of the same type - only some - but after changing enough times, all the items of the same type will eventually be the same item.

Comment: you should really avoid using `eval()` at all

Comment: please break it town into a single problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, where the problem lies, so it is as much troubleshooting (and learning). Basically the problem is, that the splice-part neither adds nor deletes the values.

About the 'eval()' - I'm aware and will clean it eventually. It was just the easiest way to not ruin the function when saving to localstorage.

Comment: Please reduce this to a code piece of just a few lines, which reproduces the problem. I can't imagine *all* these functions and repetitions (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) are relevant to the core question. We should not have to go through that noise.

Comment: I think this is as much as I can clean it up. Removed all references to adding the stats and so on (the part with eval).

Comment: `Object.assign(EQItem, LItem);` is responsible for  the *mutation* of the item you have already equipped. I don't see why you have this `Object.assign` there. It seems to only do damage without any benefit.

Comment: You're right. Don't know why I added it that way - hasn't been there all the time. Changed it to
      `Equipped[LItem.Type] = LItem;`
and we're now running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you're trying an Object-Oriented approach.

I'm not sure if I understood your problem in completeness.
Here'd be another way of implementing "Equipment" and "Inventory". Maybe you like it and it helps.

But be careful, this needs ECMAScript 6 (Babel transpiling).

```js
class Mainhand {
  static type() {
    return "MainHand";
  }
};

class Knife extends Mainhand {};
class Stick extends Mainhand {};

class Inventory {
  constructor(items) {
    this.items = items;
  }
};

class Equipment {
  constructor() {
    this.equipped = {};
  };
  
  equip(item) {
    let type = item.constructor.type();
    
    // this one is used to create a new "equipped" list instead of modifing the previous one.
    let newEquipment = Object.assign({}, this.equipped);
    newEquipment[type] = item;
    
    this.equipped = newEquipment;
  }
};

document.user = {
  inventory: new Inventory([
    new Stick(),
    new Knife(),
  ]),
  equipment: new Equipment(),
};

document.querySelectorAll('.equip').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let item = document.user.inventory.items[e.target.dataset.inventoryKey];    
    document.user.equipment.equip(item);
    
    let currentMainHandName = document.user.equipment.equipped.MainHand.constructor.name;
    
    document.getElementById("currentMainHand").innerHTML = currentMainHandName;
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="equip" data-inventory-key="0">I want a stick</button>

<button class="equip" data-inventory-key="1">I want a knife</button>

<h2>Current Mainhand</h2>
<p id="currentMainHand" style="color: red;"></p>
```